# play framework 2.3 - configuring staged/distributed apps for memory usage?

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I had a question about memory usage when distributing play applications.    If there are a number of different play applications running on the same server instance as separate services, how can a given application that is built staged or distributed be tuned to use less memory.

It seems even fairly simple applications end up taking around 1GB of RAM.   Are there some things that can be done to configure this to be more lightweight to support more of a micro services model on machines that do not have a great deal of ram?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: You mean the amount of memory assigned via `Xmx` or have you actually profiled your service?

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time looking on the playframework website, and found the stage launcher script has a -mem flag which will attempt to set heap memory and related -X memory variables.

The generated application launcher script has 1GB memory as the default heap memory when launching a staged app.

The java -X memory properties can also be specified and then used by the script.